# Making unicorn disappear for good?

Tags: support, user-interface

The unicorn and the starry mouse pointer are a bit funny at first, but soon become a nuisance.

Can they be switched off for good?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I too was unimpressed by this year's April Fools event.

It seems to have now disappeared anyway, but how to turn it off is the subject of a Meta SE Q&A: [How to disable "time travel" entirely?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325996/how-to-disable-time-travel-entirely)